# Purpose of useState with an initialize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't understand the purpose of using useState with an initializer.

Below is an example where I set a counter that persists in local storage here I have not used an arrow function to initialize it.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count")))
```

This example below uses an arrow function to initialize.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(()=>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count")))
```

Can someone explain when the arrow function would be used and for what purpose.

Comment: What if you wanted to do some operation on the data before setting the initial state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [stated in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

> The `initialState` argument is the state used **during the initial render**. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, **which will be executed only on the initial render**.

So, on passing a value, on every render the value will be calculated.

```
// Will call JSON.parse and get item "count" from local storage
// on **every** render
const [count, setCount] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count")))
```

Passing a callback will called only once.

```
// Will call JSON.parse and get item "count" from local storage
// **once** on initial render
const [count, setCount] = useState(()=>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count")))
```

In the next example, having a value `calc()` (similar to the first case) as the initial state will log "called" on every render. While having a callback, won't.

```
const calc = () => {
  console.log("called");
  return 42;
};

const App = () => {
  // value: calc() 
  // const [state, setState] = useState(calc());

  // callback : () => calc()
  const [state, setState] = useState(calc);
  return (
    <>
      {state}
      <button onClick={() => setState(p => p + 1)}>render</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit runtime-darkness-565tg]